# Chrome dev tools sources of localhost disappeared

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Sources of localhost:8080 disappeared in dev tools. When I open in incognito window, sources show again. Does anyone know why they disappeared?

[image]

Versions:

OSX 10.11.2
Chrome 47.0.2526.111 (64-bit)

Comment: Could it be caused by a browser extension? (Assuming, of course, that the extension is disabled in incognito mode.)

Comment: @jkdev I have tried to disable every extension, still not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the little folder icon beside `www` in your screenshot? This indicated a local workspace has been setup. You have most likely mapped the remote (`localhost:8080`) resources to that workspace. Which, then tells DevTools not to show those sources since they get mapped into that directory.

To verify this, go to your DevTools Settings (<kbd>F1</kbd>) then to the "Workspaces" tab. From there, check any setup workspaces for their mapped resources. You can then remove mappings if needed and try reloading the page again. If on a reload the sources are shown, then this confirms remote mapping to a local workspace was the source of hiding the remote tree.